# LinkedIn Sharing is not working properly in I.E 9 and 8

Tags: html, linkedin-api

I am using LinkedIn Sharing to share the data :

```
http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url={articleUrl}&title={articleTitle}&summary={articleSummary}&source={articleSource}
```

It's working fine except i.e. not getting what is the issue.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/3v3ry5me/) Which is working fine in all the browsers but the same thing is not working in i.e. browsers.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: For me it works fine in IE

Comment: @rJ7, Which Version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the code itself or IE, it is that the generated link includes a strange character that drives Internet Explorer crazy: ’ (and I am surprised it works on the others).

So, your generated link is:

https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=www.romans.co.uk%2fRomansImages%2fCMS%2fNewsInsights%2fNews%2fMarraways201410071155325608.jpg&title=A%20September%20to%20remember;%20Romans’%20second%20largest%20auction%20sale%20this%20year&summary=With%20the%20joys%20of%20an%20Indian%20summer%20spreading%20through%20the%20packed%20sales%20room,%20Romans%20September%20auction%20&source=www.romans.co.uk%2fRomansImages%2fCMS%2fNewsInsights%2fNews%2fMarraways201410071155325608.jpg

(notice how even SO breaks it after that funny character)

Replace/Remove that character and everything works fine:

https://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=www.romans.co.uk%2fRomansImages%2fCMS%2fNewsInsights%2fNews%2fMarraways201410071155325608.jpg&title=A%20September%20to%20remember;%20Romans%20second%20largest%20auction%20sale%20this%20year&summary=With%20the%20joys%20of%20an%20Indian%20summer%20spreading%20through%20the%20packed%20sales%20room,%20Romans%20September%20auction%20&source=www.romans.co.uk%2fRomansImages%2fCMS%2fNewsInsights%2fNews%2fMarraways201410071155325608.jpg

Parse and encode the URL so it does not contain strange characters and it will work in all the browsers.